# AsNoTracking() Method Is Missing From Context in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I need to load an entire table into memory using Entity Framework 4.0.  I have spent the last 2 hours reading about the AsNoTracking() method that should do the trick but, I cannot figure out why the method is not available on my dataContext.  Based on everything I have read, I should merely need a reference to System.Data.Entity.  Then, I should be able to use the AsNoTracking() method when loading my objects.  Am I missing something simple here?  Is this method not available in EF 4.0?  Nevertheless, below is one of the queries from my code.

```
// Working Query
var items = dbContext.Items.ToList()

// Does NOT Work (Compiler does not recognize AsNoTrackingMethod() )
var items = dbContext.Items.AsNoTracking().ToList()
```

Comment: System.Data.Entity is referenced and I'm using Entity Framework 4.0.  The documentation I encountered is not clear as to which version started supporting this method so, maybe it is a version issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`AsNoTracking()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679169%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is an extension method, which was added in Entity Framework 4.1 (as  ability to return non-cached results). That's why you don't have it in Entity Framework 4.0. I suggest you to upgrade version of Entity Framework, if it is possible (BTW current version is 6.0).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you guys know whether or not there is another way to load a bunch of objects using EF 4.0 that can be directly attached to a different context for insert?  I basically need to load a table in one db using one context and turn right around and insert the records into another database table using a different dbContext.

Comment: @Grasshopper unfortunately I didn't have such task. If you have performance issues, consider to ask question here on SO. I think there lot of experienced people

Answer (score 18):

If using EF from .NET Core use directive:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Comment: I was focusing on a problem about the entity because it didn't notify the library missing, Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

AsNoTracking() is an extension method in the DbExtensions ([EF5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking%28v=vs.103%29.aspx))/QueryableExtensions  ([EF6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.asnotracking%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)) class, which is part of the System.Data.Entity namespace. It is not missing from Entity Framework 4.1+. You simply need to remember to add a using directive for that namespace.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```